# What "detach()" on thread does? CPP

Tags: c++

I know many people asked this question, but im not "many people" and I need a different and a better explanation to understand.

The member function "detach()" what exactly it does?
I tried running the next code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void independentThread()
{
    std::cout << "Starting concurrent thread.\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(200));
    std::cout << "Exiting concurrent thread.\n";
}

void threadCaller()
{
    std::cout << "Starting thread caller.\n";
    std::thread t(independentThread);
    t.detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Exiting thread caller.\n";
}

int main()
{
    threadCaller();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
}
```

And after 5 seconds the all program closed.
I thought the program will be opened another 195 seconds after the "main" closes, because the all idea of "detach" is that is independent with the main, so in independent way, it should still run untill the all detached therades are terminates...
I read the documentation and came to here.
A better explanation - PLEASE! :)

Answer (score 0):

Detached thread is a thread you can't wait on to complete. `std::thread` destructor will check if the thread is either detached or joined, and if neither happened, will abort a program (call `std::terminate`).

After the `main()` terminates, program unconditionally terminates as well, not waiting for any threads, detached or otherwise.